# Android volley. Cannot get JSON Response from a working Rest API

Tags: java, android, json

I tested my REST service in POSTMAN and it works. I should get something like this:

```
{
    "msg": "the user was successfully created"
    ...
}
```

but in my android app in debug cannot find the response. Have I missed something or am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

```
private void registerUser(final String firstName, final String lastName,
                          final String email, final String password) {

    pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
    showDialog();

    try {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
        jsonBody.put("first_name", firstName);
        jsonBody.put("last_name", lastName);
        jsonBody.put("email", email);
        jsonBody.put("password", password);

        final String requestBody = jsonBody.toString();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response);
                hideDialog();
                ...
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("VOLLEY", error.toString());
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json";
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                try {
                    return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                    VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                String responseString = "";
                if (response != null) {
                    responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);

                }
                return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            }
        };

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In debug, the block

```
@Override
            protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                String responseString = "";
                if (response != null) {
                    responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);

                }
                return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            }
```

displays this: [image]

I have no JSON response.

Answer (score 1):

You don't see any json data because you are not generating any json response from you side. The response you see on Postman is from the api service. You have a success response from your program (i.e. Status code 201) and that's the only thing you are sending back to the client.

```
 if (response != null) {
                responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);

            }
```

You have to manipulate the response (in parseNetworkResponse module) and forward the relevant info you want to your client.

Comment: any link on how to do this?

Comment: in the response variable the only information I have is the status code. You can see it in the img above.

Comment: It should be quite simple. Convert the whole response instead of response.statusCode: Something like responseString = String.valueOf(response)

Comment: Here is what I get in logs of the response.toString() [167] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[ ] http://192.168.1.101:8000/api/v1/user 0x85bc0dd6 NORMAL 1> [lifetime=10677], [size=192], [rc=201], [retryCount=0]

Comment: Ok, maybe is not that simple: Try : responseString = String.valueOf(response(message-body)) or responseString = String.valueOf(response(response-header))  .... One of them should have your expected results.

Comment: Have you resolved this problem? I have the same issue

Comment: Do you get a response?